# ElasticSearch. Изменение значения health

Tags: база-данных, elasticsearch, индексы, полнотекстовый-поиск

При запросе `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`  ElasticSearch отвечает следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из данного рисунка видно, что имеется два индекса - .kibana и new-api. New-api индекс - это пользовательский индекс (не системный) и он имеет статус 'yellow'. Подскажите, как изменить статус индекса на `green`?

Comment: Что показывает запрос к "статусу здоровья" кластера http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health   ?

Comment: @de_frag 
`{"cluster_name":"application-cluster","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":5,"active_shards":5,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":5,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0}`

Comment: `"status":"yellow", "number_of_nodes":1`. Сделаете `number_of_nodes` 2 и более, `status` станет `green`.

Comment: @de_frag можете подсказать, как добавить ноду в кластер? Использую docker и docker-compose, `image : docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2`

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос по этой теме, и может быть кто-нибудь вам подскажет.